# Using an adjacency matrix to solve a match problem

Tags: adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to solve a deduplication issue with an adjacency matrix but my maths knowledge in this area is poor.  So if I have the following graph showing that a = b and a = c and b = d, I want to programmatically determine that a = d.

```
a -- b                 a -- b
|    |       ==>       | \    
|    |                 |  \
c    d                 c    d
```

Hope this diagram makes sense...  As a matrix, the left is (where a is 1, b is 2 c is 3 and d is 4)

```
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
```

and what I want is

```
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0
```

Sorry, I'm probably using all the wrong terms, but any help would be very much appreciated.  Even some pointers to the language I should be using so that I can research better myself would be good.